# Is it possible to mock a function imported from a Swift package?

Tags: swift, unit-testing, async-await, swift5

I have written a simple Swift package called [JwtApiClient](https://github.com/chris-kobrzak/JwtApiClient) that provides a few helper *functions* for making HTTP requests to JWToken-protected APIs that transfer data as JSON.

I am consuming one of these functions (`postJsonDictionary`) in another package:

```swift
import Foundation
import JwtApiClient

public func requestToken<T: Decodable>(
  _ username: String,
  _ password: String
) async throws -> T {
  let endpoint = "/users/login" // in the actual code this is an instance of URLComponents
                                // not String but it's irrelevant here
  let credentials = [
    "email": username,
    "password": password
  ]

  // I'd like to be able to mock this call
  return try await postJsonDictionary(endpoint!, credentials)
}
```

I was just wondering if it is possible to mock `postJsonDictionary` in a unit test to avoid making an underlying network request and to be able to assert on the parameters passed to it.

I have tried tricking my unit test into believing the function is a global but it doesn't work:

```swift
extension NSObject {
  public func postJsonDictionary<T: Decodable>(_ url: URL!, _ dictionary: [String: Any]) async throws -> T {
    try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 2 * 1_000_000_000)
    
    let fakeTokenResponse: TokenResponse = TokenResponse(token: "fake-token")
    
    return fakeTokenResponse as! T
  }
}

// XCTestCase below
```

Comment: Rather than using the global(?) function for accessing the API can you inject it into `requestToken` via a method parameter, possibly with a default to the 'production' method.  This way you can call `requestToken` in testing with a dummy method that can provide a consistent response for the test.

Comment: Thank you very much @flanker - I thought it might be possible to somehow hijack an `import` and have an equivalent of `jest.mock('path/to/package')` from the JavaScript world but it looks like I'm going to need to go with the olde good dependency injection instead.